# ejecutar codigo Jquery en AngularJS

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Estoy trabajando con maquetas y tengo el siguiente código jQuery:

```
$('.progress-bar').each(function(i,e){
    var $this = $(this);
    var $percent = $("<div class=\"percent\"></div>");
    var $value = $this.attr("data-value");
    $this.append($percent);

    $percent.css( {'background': $this.attr("data-color")});
    $percent.animate({width: $this.attr("data-percent") + '%'}, 350);

    if ($value != undefined && $value != "") {
        $divvalue = $("<span class=\"txt\">"+$value+"</span>");
        $this.append($divvalue);
        $divvalue.animate({'left': $this.attr("data-percent")+'%', opacity: 1});
    }
});
```

el cual necesito adecuarlo a Angularjs. Estoy trabajando con listas y `ng-repeat` como sigue:

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="internetPrincipal in internetListaBolsaPrincipalInternet">
        <td width="30%">{{internetPrincipal.nombreBolsa}}</td>
        <td>
            <div class="progress-bar" data-color="#d52b1e" data-percent="25" data-value="{{internetPrincipal.bolsaUtilizada}}" >
                <span>{{internetPrincipal.bolsaTotal - internetPrincipal.bolsaUtilizada}} {{internetPrincipal.unidadConsumo}} restantes</span>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td width="100">{{internetPrincipal.bolsaTotal}}{{internetPrincipal.unidadConsumo}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Como ven se ejecuta el `ng-repeat` y está generando `td` de acuerdo a lo que traiga la lista. Lo que no logro es darle el efecto que tenía con jquery.

Alguna ayuda les agradecería.

Comment: Asumo que cuando hablas de efecto jquery, estas hablando como de algún movimiento en especifico que deba hacer la ventana o la lista, podrías poner algún gif para ver cual es el efecto? o al menos hacer un fiddle de tu ejemplo corriendo con el efecto

Comment: Básicamente quieres hacer una animación de los progressbar. Agrega un gif a tu pregunta donde se vea el efecto. De lo contrario es difícil saber lo que quieres.